# how to take a picture directly within the Survey?

Tags: surveyjs

SurveyJS offers the option to use a FilePicker, but on mobile devices, this results in the File Explorer being opened. I want our users to have the ability to immediately use their camera and upload the taken picture as a file. However, I'm encountering this issue even when "allowCameraAccess" is enabled - a feature added by the SurveyJS team. I'm using the latest version of the builder, 1.9.100, and the frontend SurveyJS version, 1.9.97. My project is built with ionic/vue

[properties enabled for file type question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAFs6.png)

[screenshot in phone view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UOgh.png)

[screenshot in phone view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS2cx.png)